# Powershell: Invoke a session as Administrator

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run my script as a `ADMIN` user and install the certificates, but it only works if I run it from the command line as a Administrator. If I trigger my bat file from the other script it is installing the certificates as a local user.

```
SET PowerShellScriptPath='<FilePath>\File.ps1'
SET CertPath=%~dp0NewCSC.cer
start PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Scope LocalMachine}" 
timeout 05
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& %PowerShellScriptPath% %CertPath%"
```

Is it coz of I am using Powershell.exe to invoke for 2 times for every line its taking it as a local user? please help me out here.

Comment: To begin with you not need to use `-ExecutionPolicy` with `-Command`. It needs only to be be used with `-File`, (which is what your second PowerShell command should use), and only if an execution policy has not already been defined. You should also be aware that the Curent User Policy takes precedence over the Local Machine Policy. I should also mention that your `-Scope` is only for the single `PowerShell.exe` session, which means it is no longer active for the second `powershell.exe` command.

Comment: @Compo Is there a way that throughout the script only the single user is used which should not be as a local machine user. It should be as Administrator.

Comment: @Compo Edited the lines of scope as you mentioned. Hope now it looks good.

Comment: @Compo Is there a way to pass the user context from the batch file to the powershell script?

Comment: @Compo Yes I have edited as you suggested, problem I am facing is in the batch file, it's logged as admin, whereas in powershell script, it's a different user.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve! What do you mean by "as ADMIN user", "As a Administrator", "as Administrator", "logged as admin". Do you mean you are logged in as a different user, (named admin, Administrator, ADMIN, or anything other than the target user, but within the ADMINISTRATORS Group)? Or do you mean you are running the script elevated?

Comment: @Compo Problem statement - just to repeat - We need a way to pass the user context from the batch file to the powershell script.

Comment: Santoshkumar, if it was clear, I would not be asking. Clarify it, or cross your fingers, and hope that somebody else guesses.

Comment: If you have just the below content in your batch file, and run it elevated, i.e. "Run as administrator", when logged in as the target User, _(after changing `F:\ile\Path\File.ps1` as necessary)_, what exactly happens? ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "F:\ile\Path\File.ps1" "%~dp0NewCSC.cer"```